# Help in fitting linear mixed model in R (lme4 function)

Tags: mixed-model, modeling, model

In my design I have 48 permanent plots in 3 summits (16 plots for each summit). Plots are grouped in clusters arranged in the cardinal direction (4 plots for cardinal direction = 16 plots) and grouped into summits (16 plots for summit x 3 summits = 48 plots). I have two observations of the response variable for each plot: 2001 and 2012. The response variable is a vegetation indicator S. Plots are nested into cardinal direction and summits (plots are nested within the combinations of summit and direction?)
I 'd like to test if the vegetation indicator S is changed over time.
To do this, I'm trying to buid a linear mixed model in R (`lmer` function of `lme4` package).
I assume that time is a fixed factor as both summit and direction (3 summits and 4 directions are few to treat them as a random factor). The random factor is related to repeated measure on plot over time.
I fit this model:

```
model1<- lmer(S~time + Direction + Summit + time:Direction+time:Summit+(time|plot
```

What do you think?

Comment: The model you've specified - `lmer(S~time + Direction + Summit + time:Direction+time:Summit+(time|plot)` makes time a fixed effect (in the main effects, interactions) and, for each `plot`, there is a random slope in time and a random intercept. There are no other random effects. I'm not sure if that is what you intended. In any case, I think this question is more at home on stackoverflow, unless there is a _statistical_ question.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @LudovicoFrate. It's not clear to me whether you need / want help with the statistical content of this situation, or just how to represent your ideas in R code. Would you please edit this to clarify? If you want help understanding the statistical ideas, this Q belongs here, but if you just need help with code, it should be migrated to SO.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to get advice on setting the analysis, in other word, putting the R code aside for the moment, is my idea correct?